# Get the different value from multiple elements with the same class in Selenium for Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<span class="class_name">10</span>
<span class="class_name">20</span>
<span class="class_name">32</span>
```

The number (10, 20, 32) are variable, they could be 32, 56 and 65.

In Selenium I do:

```
findclass = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")
```

Now, my goal is take and assign number to variable like:

```
var1 = 10
var2 = 20
var3 = 32
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the actual question? What didn't work?

Comment: i don't know how take that value from html page...

Comment: Do you want to take only one span where, for example, 10?

Comment: I need to take all values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_elements_by_class_name`. It will return a list of all elements with this class name.

```
findclass = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class_name")

for i in findclass:

    print(i.text)
```

To find the second element in the list just use: `print(findclass[1].text)`.

If you are looking for a specific value you can use CSS selector or XPath, you don't need the list of all the elements...

Comment: Not work: for i in findclass:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: @JuConte see the first line in the answer... you need to change the var `findclass` don't use: `findclass = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")` use: `findclass = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class_name")` see the diffrens? insted of finding one elenemt youll find all elements!

Comment: perfect, it work! But now, how can I define the frist, the second and third value? I need to assign var1='first i.text', var2='second i.text?, ecc...

Comment: @JuConte, as you can see `get_elements`, is a list so you can get any element within the list! what do you need? do you need a specific value? or location?

Comment: I need all values, how can I define the position (or location)?

Comment: I try to explaine well... in for loop (for i in findclass) i need to take only second value. There is a solution to define the position, for example print i.text(second value)?

Comment: Just like any `list` you can get the position with `[]` it starts from `[0]` for the first one and `[1]` for the second...

Comment: @JuConte see more about lists [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: solved! Whit enumerate(findclass) it work! thank you

Answer (score 2):

@MosheSlavin was was in the right direction. However to put all the values in a *List* you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CLASS_NAME`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "class_name")))])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.class_name")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='class_name']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Why use innerHTML rather than text?

Comment: @MosheSlavin There are differences between how both of them works. In this case the output may be same using both but I prefer _innerHTML_